# why can't get this page in linux with wget/telnet?

Tags: linux, browser, ubuntu, wget

this URL *www.jinfuwu.com* can be access in windows browser,windows telnet,

but in my ubuntu server, i can't get this page:

**telnet (ubuntu):**

```
root@ubuntu:~# telnet www.jinfuwu.com 80            
Trying 121.199.111.176...
Connected to www.jinfuwu.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.jinfuwu.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Dec 2010 01:34:33 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "f671fd911c94cb1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
Date: Sun, 05 Dec 2010 10:03:21 GMT
Content-Length: 1214Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**wget (ubuntu):**

```
root@ubuntu:~# wget http://www.jinfuwu.com         
--18:10:29--  http://www.jinfuwu.com/
           => `index.html.2'
Resolving www.jinfuwu.com... 121.199.111.176
Connecting to www.jinfuwu.com|121.199.111.176|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 

Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

....
```

but in my windows ,i using telnet command, i can get the page

**telnet (windows7):**

run:

```
telnet www.jinfuwu.com 80
```

paste:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.jinfuwu.com
```

and press doubles Enter,i can see the page HTML code.

google it:

```
site:jinfuwu.com
```

google can access this site

can you tell me why?

btw: also *www.joytg.com*,same question

thanks a lot :)

Comment: The answer is here: `Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5`, it doesn't like clients from `!Windows`... Joking

Comment: Use a better server. Like Apache or gatling. Propably IIS wants `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: google it: `site:jinfuwu.com` ,google can access this site,why

Comment: @thejh,it's not my server(site),you can check this site also `www.joytg.com`,same question

Comment: FYI: it worked on my mac, using telnet (without setting crlf). You can set telnet to use send `crlf` on newlines, run `telnet` without arguments, type `set crlf`, then `open host port`. But this doesn't explain why `wget` doesn't work.

Comment: `wget` works for me. Speed is a bit slow though (~17B/s). `GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.`

Comment: Seems to work here (Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop), but it's slow. Slow like in 24Bytes/s.

Comment: `telnet` also works for me. Still very slow.

Comment: wget can get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`,but very slow,can't get the page,in windows doesn't has this problem,why?

Comment: @Zenofo, @Ramon Marco Navarro, @Ivo Wetzel, @thejh: Problem found. It's a misconfigured router, although there's a workaround. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did some further digging for you and found the root cause is due to misconfigured routers. You can read about it all [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/92727/).

The workaround that article mentions is to:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_default_win_scale
```

However, this file has changed and on newer setups you need to instead:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling
```

You will need to be root when running that though.

```
$ wget http://www.jinfuwu.com
--2010-12-05 12:58:39--  http://www.jinfuwu.com/
Resolving www.jinfuwu.com... 121.199.111.176
Connecting to www.jinfuwu.com|121.199.111.176|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12145 (12K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

100%[====================================================>] 12,145      5.19K/s   in 2.3s    

2010-12-05 12:58:43 (5.19 KB/s) - `index.html' saved [12145/12145]
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I can get the page just fine using `wget` or `curl` from MacPorts.